# only get strings from a file

Tags: java, string, file, if-statement

For example, i have a file contains one sentence:  That send, "a team to" the Super Bowl! saw on average an 18 percent increase.
I want to only get words from this file(do not want symbols, " " ! .)

My codes:

```
        File file = new File("1.txt");
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        while(s.hasNext())
        {   
            String str = s.next();
            if(str.contains(".")){

            System.out.println("has ,");

        }
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        s.close();
```

However, this code will give me words with symbols following them. For example, it will return "a, instead of just a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the scanner to use a delimiter.
Meaning it will break apart your input strings by the pattern/regex passed to the delimiter.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\s|\"|!|.");
```